# Mysql and phpmyadmin installation in RaspberryPi 3

Tags: mysql, linux, phpmyadmin, raspberry-pi3

I am trying to install mysql and phpmyadmin in my raspberrypi 3. I have followed many tutorials on the internet and specifically this link
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ozo_npQMQS8

now the problem is that while installing mysql i dont get any window in the command line asking for the password hence i am not able to set the root password..
I am able to get into mysql by "sudo"

> sudo mysql -u root

but i am not able to login through the password.
the situation is same for the phpmyadmin. the installation is correct but i am not able to login with the password.
Thanks

Comment: anyone can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i figure out the problem is with the plugin. so i have to set the plugin to mysql_native_password.

To check the plugin type

```
USE mysql;   
SELECT User, Host, plugin FROM mysql.user;
```

You may see that mysql_native_password is not there..

so to setup you may write these commands..

```
sudo mysql -u root 

 mysql> USE mysql; 
 mysql> UPDATE user SET
 plugin='mysql_native_password' WHERE User='root'; mysql> FLUSH
 PRIVILEGES; mysql> exit;

 $ service mysql restart
```

So now you will be able to login both in phpmyadmin and in console through root password.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need 'sudo' because the `-u` in `mysql -u root` specifies the user account with which to connect (and the 'mysql' command should be available for all users, not just root; if not check your path). The reason you're not being prompted for a password is because you haven't told MySQL to use a password when connecting, to do that use `-p` like `mysql -u root -p`.

If you didn't set a password during installation, then there shouldn't be a password in which case `mysql -u root` should have worked for you. Once you've connected, you could set a password (which you probably ought to do for the two user accounts with username root and host '%' and 'localhost' (there may also be one for an IPv6 address). After setting the password, of course you'll need to use it when logging in with the `-p` flag.

If you're having trouble with phpMyAdmin, show us the error message and relevant part of your configuration file (`config.inc.php`).